# Jquery touchSwipe plugin Page Scrolling on iOs devices

Tags: ios, scroll, jquery-plugins, swipe, touchswipe

I'm using *Jquery* plugin *touchSwipe* and I encounter an issue. I can't scroll on my iPad (or iPhone) over the section where I activated the swipe handler.
I've activated the `allowPageScroll:"vertical"` option. It works on Android.

If you want to test by yourself you can try to scroll up/down (on an iOs device of course) the first "Swipe me" section of [this page](http://labs.rampinteractive.co.uk/touchSwipe/demos/Page_scrolling.html).

How can I fix it ? Why it doesn't work ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is an outstanding bug with the plugin (likely due to irregular behavior from the iOS devices). The bug was reported in December 2015 and has yet to be resolved by the developer ([link to issue](https://github.com/mattbryson/TouchSwipe-Jquery-Plugin/issues/275)).

Several work-arounds have been offered by the community, but each comes with the potential for negative side-effects that are worse than the problem they aim to solve.